# Store all dates in one table

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

I have many tables in my database and each one has one or two fields which is DATE field. This is increasing my database size so I am thinking to store all DATE fields in one table and add relationship to all tables. Is it possible and a good idea or not?

```
My database, example:
Old design
tblCustomer  = > CustomerID, Surname,    Name,        DateFirstVisit,  DateStopped
tblOrder     = > OrderID,    CustomerID, DateOrder,   Order,           DateShiped
tblPayment   = > PaymentID,  CustomerID, DatePayment, Price,           DateCheck


New design
tblCustomer  = > CustomerID, Surname,    Name,        DateInID,  DateOutID
tblOrder     = > OrderID,    CustomerID, DateInID,    Order,     DateOutID
tblPayment   = > PaymentID,  CustomerID, DateInID,    Price,     DateOutID
tblDateIn    = > DateInID,   DateIn
tblDateOut   = > DateOutID,  DateOut
```

Can I combine tblDateIn and tblDateOut?

Thank you...

Comment: That doesn't make much sense - you'll still be storing the dates, and now you have to join those tables multiple times to your other tables. An OrderDate belongs on the orders table, A payment date belongs on the payments table. How big is your database that you are worried about the size of it ?

Comment: _Is it possible?_ Yes. _A good idea or not?_ Not. Except, perhaps, for some very special case which this is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, yes, you can further normalize your database this way. You could go so far as to have a Dates table that just has every date in it and use those dates by reference to a DateID, but this is over-normalization.

In addition to making simple queries more complicated because you will have to join to the dates table every time, I think you'll find that you don't save that much space and might possibly use more space. I don't know for certain what Access uses, but dates are typically stored internally as decimal values or an integer representing a count of seconds since a starting date. In any case, the space you would save in your tables by having an integer key versus Access' internal date value would be tiny and likely offset by having additional tables and indexes involved in foreign keys.